# Regex: How to detect a string inside quotation marks, but include escaped quotes?

Tags: php, regex

I have a really simple task, write a single regular expression, that would return a string inside quotation marks:

```
"this is string"
```

...but also include any escaped quotes:

```
"this is \" also a string"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So it always starts and end with a "? Did you try with ^" and "$ ?

Comment: No, it doesn't always end with ", the regex ends there, but there is all kinds of stuff after the closing "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, be sure that regular expressions are what you really want. They have a habit of getting ugly.

But if you are sure, this should do the trick:

```
"((\\.|[^\\"])*)"
```

The outer-brackets are only so that you can fetch the content of the string without the quotes. If you don't need that, you can just use `"(\\.|[^\\"])*"`.

To send this to PHP, you can use a string with single quotes (which does no escaping);

```
'"((\\.|[^\\"])*)"'
```

or if you must use double-quotes, escape it as needed:

```
"\"((\\\\.|[^\\\\\"])*)\""
```